# remove annoying highlighting Netbeans 7.2 C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, highlight, netbeans-7.2

Anytime I write a variable's name I get this annoying IDK green or yellow highlight . What is it ? how to get rid of it?
Image here:
[image]

Comment: Is it constant or temporary behavior? If it is constant, go to `Tools>Options`, select the `Fonts & Colors` tab. Select `C++` in the `Language` dropdown. Then, from the other dropdown, select whatever the variable is called. I don't have C++ installed. In Java, I have `local variable declaration`, it should be similar. You can choose foreground and background color from there.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I thought what I have discovered might help others. :)

I had the same annoying problem and no matter what I could not remove the highlighting with the Tools->Fonts & Colours option mentioned here.

What actually did work is the Tools->Editor->Highlighting and turn off the "Mark Occurrences of Symbol Under Caret".

[image]

Comment: In Nebeans 8, just unchecking "Keep Marks' works for me.

Comment: Joseph Quinsey thank you thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

You can change the background color in Tools → Options → Fonts & Colors. Here you select Language: "C++" and Category: "Mark Occurrences." Select a different background color and be happy!

[image: Screenshot of NetBeans 6.9.1 Options / Fonts & Colors window]

It was so annoying to me too.

Answer (score 5):

Simply deselect the icon I just "highlighted" with the black border

or type Alt+Shift+H

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem with PHP.

Tools -> options -> font & color then choose your language and it should be there...

(in php, the name of the variable is "Mark Occurences")

Answer (score 3):

[image: netbeans yellow highlighting error]
I had this annoying problem on Netbeans 8.0.2, this is how I solved it step by step :

1) Tools > Options

2) Editor > Highlighting

3) Select Language Example - PHP

4) Uncheck the option ' Mark Occurrences of Symbol Under Caret'

5) Uncheck the option 'keep marks' before you apply changes to remove all the existing marks. ( I found out that leaving this option checked keeps the existing highlight)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum](https://forums.netbeans.org/post-88796.html), in order to manually edit the file to change the 'mark occurrences' color, you can look for the file to edit within this archive (Should work for other languages. Linked forum used Groovy):

```
\.netbeans\7.0\modules\org-netbeans-modules-[LANGUAGE NAME]-editor.jar
```

Look for this file:

```
\org\netbeans\modules\[LANGUAGE NAME]\editor\resources\FontColors.xml
```

Ctrl+F for `mark-occurrences` and then edit the `bgcolor` value to what you want.